# How to not return any element or Null when variable is null or empty?

Tags: php

I had this:

```
<?php

global $mConfig;

return [
  __DIR__ . "/../stores/config.{$_ENV['config_environment']}.php",
  __DIR__ . '/config.php',
];
```

but it kept throwing a warning about the empty variable inside of ENV.

And then I tried this, but I still get a warning about the empty variable:

```
<?php

global $mConfig;

return [
 $_ENV['config_environment'] ? __DIR__ . "/../stores/config.{$_ENV['config_environment']}.php" : null,
  __DIR__ . '/config.php',
];
```

How do you change this so that if $_ENV['config_environment'] is not set it doesn't return anything? The confusing part about this is that it's not inside a function so I am not sure how to go about it. I don't want null, because I am doing a foreach like this:

```
foreach (require(__DIR__ . "/../../../configs/config_files.php") as $pathname) {
```

Comment: Did you try `isset($_ENV['config_environment']) ?...` ?

Comment: This also seems like a simple `if` statement could be used, and I think it would make the code a little clearer even.

Comment: Can't use an `if` statement inside the `return` statement.  ADyson is correct, use `isset`.  A variable can be set but still null or or empty:  `$_ENV['config_environment'] = 0`